# Getting list of ids of enabled checkboxes angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I have a table in which I have particular column as checkboxes. I have assigned a empty list. So what I want is that I want the ids of the rows of the enabled checkboxes. Say for example if the checkboxes are enabled in id 4 and 5 then the list should be [4,5]

**Sample data:**

```
 { id:1,
  name: "A",
  qty: 6,
  value: 10
},
{  id:2,
  name: "B",
  qty: 4,
  value: 10
},
{  id:3,
  name: "C",
  qty: 1,
  value: 10
}
```

**Getting data from service:**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
  this.listes = res;
});
```

}

**List name:**

```
  checkboxselectlist: any[];
```

My stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vnwed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you.

1. You need to pass an event handler to ngchange.
2. In the event handler, you can get the element id which should help you to update your list. `checkboxselectlist`

```
// in your app.component.ts
filterResults(obj: any, e: any) {
   console.log(obj); 
   console.log(e.currentTarget.checked); // true or false
   // UPDATE LIST HERE
 }

// in your app.component.html
<tr *ngFor="let list of listes; index as i">

<td>{{i+1}}</td>
<td>{{list.name}}</td>
<td>{{list.qty}}</td>
<td>{{list.value}}</td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1"
            name="vehicle1"
           (change)="filterResults(list, $event)">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Tried that but getting this error "Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'."

Comment: i have updated my answer after testing on stackblitz

Comment: How do I get the id. I have tried this pls check.   filterResults(obj: any, e: any) {
   console.log(obj); 
   console.log(e.currentTarget.checked);
   this.checkboxselectlist.push(this.listes.id)
 }

Comment: `filterResults(obj: any, e: any) {
    if(e.currentTarget.checked == true) {
    this.checkboxselectlist.push(obj.id); 
}
  }`

Comment: I cant understand the code u  sent.? Why console.log log instead of pushing values to the list

Comment: check my above comment. it should do the job.

Comment: I debugged it and found error obj was undefined and in console this error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwjath?file=src/app/app.component.ts

check these links

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwjath?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: BOth have same code that too console.log stuffs

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwjath

check project on above link.

Comment: When I run this in vscode I get this error in console  "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: you need to initialize your list like this: 
`checkboxselectlist: any[] = [];`

Comment: I did that bro but inside the list the values are undefined

Comment: I am applying the same code u wrote here on my vs code. While debigging inside the list the values I get is this             checklist:(2) [undefined, undefined]  0: undefined
1: undefined
length: 2

Comment: this will happen only if you click on checkbox and Id of object is undefined

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake sorry. Thanks for the help